# iOS - Use server external IP in FTP

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, nsurlconnection, nsoutputstream

I am developing an app that uploads data directly to FTP server i am using apple's **simpleFTPSample** example. All is working fine except when i try to access FTP outside my local network i can not connect to FTP server.

I got the problem that is i need to use server external IP. I am using universal IP to connect server but how will i pass the indication to code to use server external Ip? Do i have to change some property of **NSOutputStream** or have to do something else?

Update: I have been modifing **NSOutputStream** like:

```
CFWriteStreamRef writeStreamRef = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, ( __bridge CFURLRef) url);

    //CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyFTPUsePassiveMode,kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyFTPFetchResourceInfo, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyFTPProxy,kCFNull);
    //CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamSSLIsServer, kCFBooleanFalse);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName, (__bridge CFStringRef) self.usernameText.text);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStreamRef, kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword, (__bridge CFStringRef) self.passwordText.text);


    self.networkStream = ( __bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *) writeStreamRef;
```

My guess is that i have to do something with **NSOutputStream** or **NSUrlConnection** but i can't find anywhere.

Comment: please, can you show us you connection code?? to help you in a better way

Comment: I am using simpleFTPSample the code provided by Apple. I will post the code for the modification i did with NSOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using manual commands passing to FTP Server.